# Using dot product to determine if point lies on a plane

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, vector-graphics

Given A: a point, B: A point known to exist on a plane P, C: the normal of plane P. Can I determine if A lies on P by the result of a dot product between (A - B) and C being zero? (or within a certain level of precision, I'll probably use 0.0001f)

I might just be missing some obvious mathematical flaw but this seems to be much simpler and faster than transforming the point to a triangle's coordinate space a.la the answer to [Check if a point is inside a plane segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638064/check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-plane-segment/9638906#9638906)

So secondly I guess; if this is a valid check, would it be computationally faster than using matrix transformations if all I want is to see if the point is on the plane? (and not whether it lies within a polygon on said plane, I'll probably keep using matrix transforms for that)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that B lies on the plane through A and with normal P if and only if dotProduct(A-B,P) = 0.

To estimate speed for this sort of thing, you can pretty much just count the multiplications. This formula just has three multiplications, so its going to be faster than pretty much anything to do with matrices.

Comment: Would you be able to post an example with data/mathematics? Specifically to answer the title of the question which is a top result for a noob such as myself who is trying to learn how to do this kind of comparison in the first place; much less care if its optimized and how expensive it is.

Comment: @ThorSummoner: The mathematics isn't too bad. Note that in this context, normal just means perpendicular. The normal to a plane is, by definition, the vector that is perpendicular to all the vectors that lie in a plane. Since A is in the plane, A - B (or B - A) is a vector in the plane. That vector is perpendicular to P if and only if dotProduct(A-B,P) = 0. Does that help?

Comment: What about the plane's distance from the origin? That would have to be taken into account for this to be accurate.

Comment: The distance from the origin turns out to be abs(dotProduct(A,P)) / length(P). This is the length of the component of A in the direction of P. Are you expecting something more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are closer to the proof, but not sufficient. It should be intuitive that using just two vectors is insufficient because for one, point P can be above the plane and a vertical line drawn from it to the plane would still generate a zero dot product with any single vector lying on the plane, just as it would for a point P on the plane. The necessary and sufficient condition is that if two vectors can be found on the plane then the actual plane is represented unambiguously by the cross product of the two vectors i.e.
**w**=**u**x**v**. By definition, **w** is the area vector, which is **always** perpendicular to the plane.

Then, for the point P in question, constructing a third vector **s** from either **u** or **v** should be tested against **w** by the dot product, s.t.

**w**.**s**=|**w**||**s**|cos(90)=0 implies that the point P lies on the plane described by **w**, which is in turn described by vectors **u** and **v**.